# load a set of objects that begin with the same character

Tags: r

i have 8 RDS files stored:

```
Value_1.rds
value_2.rds ...
value_8.rds
```

how would I laod all the RDS files separately
so that the first one would be

```
model_1 <- readRDS("value_1.rds")
model_2 <- readRDS("value_2.rds")
```

without having to wrote that out multiple times

Comment: you can use `lapply()`, then you'll have them in a list. Which is probably better anyhow, since they seem to be related

Answer (score 0):

following shs' comment, this would work for you:

```
filenames <- list.files(pattern = "^value")  
models <- lapply(filenames, readRDS)
```